# Telescope in a crater? How different are the bowl shapes?

Tags: space-telescope, construction, radio-telescope, crater

When building large stationary single-dish radio telescopes, one of the constraints to location is that the landscape should already have approximately the right shape, cutting down on construction costs.

When looking at geologically inactive bodies (say, the Moon), an obvious feature of the landscape is all the craters. They look "bowl shaped". Radio telescopes are also "bowl shaped".

It's evident that such craters are a good starting point for building a telescope dish, but *how good?* In general: **How much does the geometry of an impact crater differ from a telescope?**

Comment: As a starting point the [Arecibo telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_Telescope) was built in a natural sink hole. [This study](https://physics.uwo.ca/~debruyn/pdfs/simon_shapes_PRE.pdf) into impact crater shapes in *granular* material suggest the shapes of crater is hyperbolic. Radio dishes are parabolic. If craters in rock are hyperbolic then its a matter of fitting a 3D parabola into a 3D hyperbola.

Comment: [This study](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/maps.122010) which uses the shadows found in some craters, states "personal observations indicate that, like Linne, a great majority of simple craters' shapes lie between parabolic and conical, and are therefore of the hyperbolic form rather than the elliptical."

Comment: different but somewhat related questions in Astronomy SE [Why can't we build a huge stationary optical telescope inside a depression similar to the FAST?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41023/7982) and [Is there an advantage to the equatorial region of the far side of the moon for a radio telescope or would any crater on the far side work?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36959/7982)

Comment: It might be easier to just build the structure in space rather than go to the bother of using the lunar surface with its bothersome gravity.